File uploader works on computer but not mobile
I have coded into my website a file uploader and it works perfectly when used on the computer and a file is uploaded. But when i access the website on my iPhone i am not able to upload anything. The ability to pick what to upload appears but it doesn't upload anything. Once the file is uploaded it is supposed to say 'Uploaded!'. Does anyone know what the issue might be?
The website URL is - https://laundryday.nyc/partner.html#partnershipagreement


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const dropContainer = document.querySelector('.drop-container');
  const input = document.querySelector('.drop-container input');
  const maxFileSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5MB limit
  const allowedTypes = ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'application/pdf']; // Add allowed file types

  dropContainer.addEventListener('click', () => {
    input.click();
  });

  input.addEventListener('change', () => {
    const file = input.files[0];

    if (file) {
      if (!allowedTypes.includes(file.type)) {
        alert("Invalid file type. Only JPEG, PNG, and PDF files are allowed.");
        input.value = ""; // Clear the input
        dropContainer.querySelector('.drop-title').textContent = "Click to upload";
        return;
      }

      if (file.size > maxFileSize) {
        alert("File size exceeds 5MB. Please upload a smaller file.");
        input.value = ""; // Clear the input
        dropContainer.querySelector('.drop-title').textContent = "Click to upload";
        return;
      }

      dropContainer.querySelector('.drop-title').textContent = 'Uploaded!';
    }
  });
});
.drop-container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: 2px dashed #7ba3b7;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.drop-container input {
  display: none;
}

.drop-container:hover {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  transition: 1s;
}

.drop-title {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #7ba3b7;
  font-weight: bold;
}
<section id="partnershipagreement" class="security section container">
  <div class="security__container grid">
    <div class="security__data">
      <h2 class="section__title-center">Partnership Agreement</h2>
      <p class="security__description">
        Download our partnership agreement and send back an executed copy via our submission portal below or through
        <a style="color: rgb(101, 174, 238);" href="mailto:laundrydaynyc@gmail.com">our email.</a>
      </p>
      <br/>
      <a class="button" href="#about">Download</a>

      <br/><br/><br/><br/>

      <!-- New Document Submission Form -->
      <form id="document-upload-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="https://formsubmit.co/laundrydaynyc@gmail.com" method="POST">
        <label class="drop-container">
                        <span class="drop-title">click to upload</span>
                        <input type="file" name="partnership agreement" required>
                      </label>
        <br/><br/><br/>
        <button class="button" style="border: none; font-size: 17px; cursor: pointer;" type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <img class="svg__img svg__color" src="./assets/partnerassets/img/partnershipagreementpic.png">
  </div>
</section>




"my phone" apple or android? I don't understand why you change .drop-title to Uploaded since merely selecting a file does not upload it - you'd have to click the Submit button to actually upload anything

Apple @JaromandaX

So, Safari - Interesting fact, recently, (like in the last week) I've seen 2 or 3 similar questions to this, complaining that Safari doesn't behave the same as Chromium/Firefox regarding file selection. I'll see if I can find them. Maybe they've been solved

Interesting, would be curious to see that. But just to test, i just tried on Chrome and had the same issue. @JaromandaX

I get the upload twice in Chrome on OSX from the snippet I made you

@ohmygodimpregnant That's because every browser on iOS basically is a wrapper around safari, because apple won't allow alternative browsers using their own rendering engine on iOS.

@mplungjan  Chrome on OSX and Chrome on iOS are two very different things. Wheres the first one is a "real" chrome by google, the latter is -- following Apples restrictions -- only a wrapper around Safari. So something working in Chrome on OSX doesn't say anything about Chrome on iOS.

Your code looks more or less OK, but I have two suggestions:

Use the accept attribute on the file input element, then the use can only select files of this type.
Use the build-in form validation to show a message to the user. For testing the file size you can use a hidden input element where the value is updated when you pick a new file and the max size property is set to a given value.



const maxFileSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5MB limit

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  let form = document.getElementById('document-upload-form');
  form.filesize.max = maxFileSize;

  form.partnershipagreement.addEventListener('change', partnershipagreementChanged);
  form.filesize.addEventListener('invalid', filesizeInvalid, true);
});

function filesizeInvalid(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  let form = e.target.form;
  if(e.target.validity.rangeOverflow){
    form.querySelector('.message').textContent = e.target.dataset.rangeoverflow;
  }
}

function partnershipagreementChanged(e) {
  let form = e.target.form;
  let file = e.target.files[0];

  form.querySelector('.message').textContent = '';
  
  if (file) {
    form.filesize.value = file.size;
    let valid = form.reportValidity();
    if(valid){
      form.querySelector('.message').textContent = 'Uploaded!';
    }
  }
}
.drop-container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: 2px dashed #7ba3b7;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.drop-container input {
  display: none;
}

input[name="filesize"] {
  display: none;
}

.drop-container:hover {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  transition: 1s;
}

.drop-title {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #7ba3b7;
  font-weight: bold;
}
<section id="partnershipagreement" class="security section container">
  <div class="security__container grid">
    <div class="security__data">
      <h2 class="section__title-center">Partnership Agreement</h2>
      <p class="security__description">
        Download our partnership agreement and send back an executed copy via our submission portal below or through
        <a style="color: rgb(101, 174, 238);" href="mailto:laundrydaynyc@gmail.com">our email.</a>
      </p>
      <p><a class="button" href="#about">Download</a></p>

      <!-- New Document Submission Form -->
      <form id="document-upload-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/formsubmit" method="POST">
        <label class="drop-container">
          <span class="drop-title">click to upload</span>
          <span class="message"></span>
          <input type="file" name="partnershipagreement" required accept="image/jpeg,image/png,application/pdf">
        </label>
        <input type="number" name="filesize" required data-rangeoverflow="File size exceeds 5MB. Please upload a smaller file.">
        <button class="button" style="border: none; font-size: 17px; cursor: pointer;" type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>



